# AEM Rich Text Editor to edit colors

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, adobe, aem, rte

Is there a property in the `Rich Text Editor` that would allow you to edit the text's color as well ?

This is my current dialog:

```xml
<lifeSavings
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    value="Lifetime Savings"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/richtext"
    fieldDescription="Enter Lifetime Savings title"
    fieldLabel="Lifetime Savings title"
    name="./lifesavings"
    textIsRich="true"
    useFixedInlineToolbar="{Boolean}true">
    <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <format
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            features="*"/>
    </rtePlugins>
    <uiSettings jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <cui jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <inline
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                toolbar="[format#bold,format#italic,format#underline]">

            </inline>
        </cui>
    </uiSettings>
</lifeSavings>
```

Comment: There is no OOTB plugin available to add colour to the text AFAIK. However, you can leverage the [Styles plugin](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/rich-text-editor.html#StylesText) to define the class names and add colours to those classes via CSS or you can use a custom implementation detailed [in this blog](http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2017/06/aem-63-touch-ui-rte-rich-text-editor-color-picker-plugin-inplace-dialog-edit.html)

Answer (score -1):

No, there isn't. but, you can use [Color Picker Plugin](http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2018/05/aem-64-touch-ui-rte-rich-text-editor-color-picker-plugin.html).